# SharePoint 2013 Hosted App Ribbon Tab/Buttons inside app web

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I've seen lot's of examples how to add a ribbon tab/buttons on host web (not app web). Can somebody tell if it's possible to ad a ribbon tab/buttons to the app web itself? I want to build an app and use the ribbon as the navigation from-to different pages inside my app.

By default there is just one single ribbon tab called Browse inside the app web. How can I add a new ribbon and buttons and have them visible at all time ... ?